# Pythonで，AttributeError: __exit__　のエラーが出たのですが，解消するためにどのようにコードを修正したらよいかわかりません

Tags: python

質問下部に示すPythonのコードで，以下のエラーメッセージが出て対処の仕方がわかりません．

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LSVM_multi.py", line 62, in <module>
    with multiprocessing.Pool(Thread_num) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

下記のPythonのコードをどのように修正したらよいかご教授宜しくお願いします．

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import csv
import multiprocessing

inputFilename = "tvCorrelationCoefALL_NTrials.csv"
outputFilename = "result_linearSVM_L2_L2.csv"


# csv読み込み
# 1次元: [1列目, 2列目] = [係数, (クラス1, クラス2) = (1, -1)]
data = np.loadtxt(inputFilename, delimiter=",")

X = data[:,0]   # 係数を取得
y = data[:,1]   # クラスラベルを取得

print("file read complete")

X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

# --------------------------------------

# 試行回数（中央値をとるため奇数）
iteration = 101
iteration += 1

# 使用するCPUコア数
Thread_num = 2

# 結果格納の配列
result = []

def getArr(X,y):
    iterArr = []
    # for文でCの最適値を算出
    for i in [1]+list(range(10, 10001, 10)):
        # 線形SVMのインスタンスを生成
        model = svm.LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge',dual=True, C=i, max_iter=1000000)

        # モデルの学習．fit関数
        model.fit(X, y)

        # 境界線
        line = -model.intercept_ / model.coef_

        # 配列
        iterArr.append(line)

    return iterArr


def wrapper_getArr(args):
    return getArr(*args)


for k in range(0, int(iteration/Thread_num), 1):
    variable = []
    for i in range(Thread_num):
        variable.append([X,y])

    with multiprocessing.Pool(Thread_num) as p:
        # (X,y)
        iterArr = p.map(wrapper_getArr, variable)

    for temp in iterArr:
        # 配列に連結
        result.append(temp)


    # 確認
    print(k)


# 結果をCSV出力
with open(outputFilename, 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(result)


print("Program end")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実行環境が`python 2.7`など`3.3`より前のバージョンの場合は、`with multiprocessing.Pool`で質問に記載された[例外が出ます](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25968716)。

#### テストコード例

```
import multiprocessing

def power(n):
    return n * n

def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as p:
        res = p.map(power, list(range(3)))
        print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**python 3.6**

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

**python 2.7**

```
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 13, in main
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_cores) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

バージョン問題に該当する場合は、リンク先の回答や下記の回避コードのように[`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)の使用を検討してください。

#### 回避コード例

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

def power(n):
    return n * n

def main():
    with closing(Pool(2)) as p:
        res = p.map(power, list(range(3)))
        print(res)
        p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．回避コード例のように`with multiprocessing.Pool(Thread_num) as p:` -> `with closing(Pool(Thread_num)) as p:`に変更し，`p.terminate`を追加すれば問題は解消されるということですか？

Comment: 先程回答していただいたことに対する質問を実践したら期待する動作しました．ご教授ありがとうございます．